# SortedSet in Grails doesn't work

Tags: java, grails, groovy, comparable, sortedset

I want to use a `SortedSet` with Grails, but all I get is a MissingMethodException.

The class that contains the sorted set looks like this:

```
class SystemUser {

    SortedSet organisations
    // ... some other fields

    static hasMany = [organisations: Organisation]
    static belongsTo = [Organisation]

}
```

... and the class implementing `Comparable` like this:

```
class Organisation implements Comparable {

    String name
    // ... some other fields

    static hasMany = [users: SystemUser]

    int compareTo(other) {
        return name.comparteTo(other.name)
    }

}
```

When I try to save a SystemUser object I get this Exception message:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.lang.String.comparteTo() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [ABC]
Possible solutions: compareTo(java.lang.String), compareTo(java.lang.Object)
```

My example is almost identical with the [example from the official reference](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/5.%20Object%20Relational%20Mapping%20%28GORM%29.html#5.2.4%20Sets,%20Lists%20and%20Maps).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> No signature of method:
>   java.lang.String.**comparteTo**() is
>   applicable for argument types

See the problem now?

Comment: hmpf, only a typo! (`compar_t_eTo`) Welcome to the world of dynamic typing ;-)

Comment: or use and IDE that tries to help a bit more ;)

Comment: I tried NetBeans which is horrible slow in Groovy mode, SpringSource Toolsuite which displayed a lot of non existing errors, but now I'm trying IntelliJ and it feels good.